# identify the issue with unscratched laptop screen with "physical damage"

Tags: laptop-repair

my laptop's screen ceased to work a few days ago and I went to the repair and they told me that it is likely due to physical damage even though no crack is visible on the screen. They showed me a picture of where the screen is broken but I can hardly see anything. I'm wondering if you can explain what is wrong with the screen in the picture that they showed me so that I can repair it.

I bought it in Best Buy and I send them to repair and they refused because of it being physical damage. My laptop model is Acer Aspire A515-510-5

[image]

Comment: The areas circled in the picture might be some separation in the layers of the screen.  However, that would show up as a visible pattern, not total failure of the screen to work.  Take it to a different repair shop.  What this one is telling you would not explain why the screen would cease to work.

Comment: Actually you can quite clearly see this is physical damage. The screen is destroyed and it will need to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Screens do not need to be physically damaged on the outside to be physically damaged. Stepping on a closed laptop, placing heavy items on top of a closed laptop or any type of pressure above what your laptop case can support would cause this type of damage.